# How to set Height and width for a object in Xcode 10? If we set value it says fixed constraint may cause clipping

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Should I give width and Height for an object like button while setting layout? 
 If I use Greater than or equal to option, It expands the button in bigger screens?
How to make a button stay in same size regardless of the device its being viewed? 
Is it a good practise to design like this ? or the object should get bigger for bigger screens?

Sorry about too many questions. Just breaking my head for days.

Thanks in Advance Guys

Comment: You should use constraints, to determine distance from left, right, top or bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it's quite a bad practice to set width and height for a button. Because the size of its content might expand depending on the user's settings (accessibility settings, for instance).

It's better just to set the **top+leading** *OR* **top+trailing** *OR* **bottom+leading**, etc...

This is mostly sufficient to make the button "look the same" on different devices (it will indeed be a little bigger on bigger screens).

And remember, as of constraints, less is better than many. When your component is placed and its constraints are all blue, test if it works as you expect and if yes, don't add more constraints. As beginners, we tend to over-constraint and it generates issues.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response.

I have tried to keep it minimal. But still if I keep a button it looks good on all the models of simulator except the ones which are quite smaller in display size. I have designed on iPhone 8 and It look perfect on all iPads and Iphone screen bigger than 8. But the issue seems to appear when trying to look it on 5s or SE.

any help?

Comment: So you have something like a view at the right or left of your button and you don't want the button to come over it for small screens, right?

Comment: If it's the case, let's say your button in on the left and the view on the right, you may add a (`Greater Than or Equal`) Trailing Space constraint: ctrl+drag from the button to the view and choose `Horizontal Spacing`. Then, edit this constraint and change the `Equal` to `Greater Than or Equal`, and set the constant to `Use standard value`. And yes, you will have 3 constraints ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on yours app design.

Many built-in UIKit views (including buttons) have their own (intrinsic) size. So it is not necessary to define size explicitly, but you can do this if you want. Remember that you shouldn't make excessive use of expicit sizes as this can lead to non-adaptive design.

In most cases it's worth to allow view to have its intrinsic height but constrain its width in some way (for example, in percents to superview's width, set minimum/maximum allowed value etc). But in any case you should define position where your view will be displayed.